# Unicode domain name in Nginx server_name

Tags: nginx, punycode

I am trying to set up a server with a domain name called "privatinstruktør.dk" but keeps getting redirected to the default "welcome to nginx" page.

I have tried to type in the server_name like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name privatinstruktør.dk;

  location / {
    root /var/www/privat;
  }
}
```

but that did not work. So I tried using regular expressions like:

```
server_name "~^privatinstrukt(.+)r\.dk$";
```

and

```
server_name "~^privatinstrukt(.*)r\.dk$";
```

and even

```
server_name "~^privat(.*)$";
```

But all fails and I am redirected to the default page. Does anyone have a hint on how to fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Configure a Unicode domain name using [punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) format in nginx:

```
server_name xn--privatinstruktr-jub.dk;
```

Comment: Do you really need both?

Comment: @Phil no, the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#idn) have specifically this to say: "Internationalized domain names (IDNs) should be specified using an ASCII (Punycode) representation in the server_name directive."

Answer (score 3):

Use only the [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) name:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name xn--privatinstruktr-jub.dk;

  location / {
    root /var/www/privat;
  }
}
```

which is what the [Nginx Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#idn) say:

> Internationalized domain names (IDNs) should be specified using an ASCII (Punycode) representation in the server_name directive